# Namespace in XSL, copying attribute values from a template XML file to update a translated file

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

The task of my XSL file is to get the attribute 'symbol' value from a template source file and put it in a translated file, where the message numbers in both files match. This update seems to be working, but somehow I have ended up with namespace problems. I have no idea why, because the template file, the translation file and the resulting file should all have exactly the same structure.

First, I was getting `xmlns` attributes in the Message elements. After some googling I found a way to get rid of them. But now I am not getting the `xmlns` attribute in the `<Area>` element, where I really want it.

Why is this re-namespacing not working with me?
How can I get it working?

My XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:aaa="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc" exclude-result-prefixes="aaa">
<!-- Transform -s:"translation.xml" -xsl:"merge_files.xsl" -o:"updated_translation.xml" +templateFile="source.xml" -versionmsg:off -->

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="templateFile"/>

    <xsl:variable name="templateDoc" select="$templateFile/aaa:Area" />
    <xsl:variable name="source" select="/" />

    <!--
    <xsl:template match="aaa:Area">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    -->

    <!-- Replacement of the traditional identity rule to avoid getting namespace info in the Message elements. -->
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:template>

    <!-- Getting everything except @symbol from the translation. @symbol is fetched from source/template file. -->
    <xsl:template match="aaa:Message">  
        <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="@number"/>
        <Message xmlns:abb="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc" number="{$messageNumber}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$templateDoc/aaa:Message[@number=$messageNumber]/@symbol"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Area areaName="YYY" areaNo="2" lang="en" xmlns="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc">
  <Message number="1" symbol="TWINKLE_TWINKLE_LITTLE_STAR">
    <Title>Twinkle Twinkle Little Star</Title>
    <Description>Twinkle, twinkle, little star, How I wonder what you are. Up above the world so high, Like a diamond in the sky.</Description>
  </Message>
  <Message number="2" symbol="SPIDER_SONG1">
    <Title>Itsy-Bitsy Spider</Title>
    <Description>The itsy-bitsy spider climbed up the water spout. Down came the rain and washed the spider out.</Description>
  </Message>
  <Message number="3" symbol="BLACK_SHEEP">
    <Title>Baa, baa, black sheep</Title>
    <Description>Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool? Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!</Description>
  </Message>
</Area>
```

My input translation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Area areaName="YYY" areaNo="2" lang="sv" xmlns="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc">
  <Message number="1" symbol="TWINKLE_STAR">
    <Title>Blinka lilla stjärna</Title>
    <Description>Blinka lilla stjärna där, hur jag undrar vad du är. Fjärran lockar du min syn, lik en diamant i skyn.</Description>
  </Message>
  <Message number="3" symbol="WHITE_SHEEP">
    <Title>Bä, bä, vita lamm</Title>
    <Description>Bä, bä, vita lamm, har du någon ull? Ja, ja, kära barn, jag har säcken full.</Description>
  </Message>
</Area>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Area areaName="YYY" areaNo="2" lang="sv" xmlns="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc">
   <Message number="1" symbol="TWINKLE_TWINKLE_LITTLE_STAR">
      <Title>Blinka lilla stjärna</Title>
      <Description>Blinka lilla stjärna där, hur jag undrar vad du är. Fjärran lockar du min syn, lik en diamant i skyn.</Description>
   </Message>
   <Message number="3" symbol="BLACK_SHEEP">
      <Title>Bä, bä, vita lamm</Title>
      <Description>Bä, bä, vita lamm, har du någon ull? Ja, ja, kära barn, jag har säcken full.</Description>
   </Message>
</Area>
```

This is my output now, where xmlns in the 'Area' element is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Area areaName="YYY" areaNo="2" lang="sv">
   <Message number="1" symbol="TWINKLE_TWINKLE_LITTLE_STAR">
      <Title>Blinka lilla stjärna</Title>
      <Description>Blinka lilla stjärna där, hur jag undrar vad du är. Fjärran lockar du min syn, lik en diamant i skyn.</Description>
   </Message>
   <Message number="3" symbol="BLACK_SHEEP">
      <Title>Bä, bä, vita lamm</Title>
      <Description>Bä, bä, vita lamm, har du någon ull? Ja, ja, kära barn, jag har säcken full.</Description>
   </Message>
</Area>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show an example of your current (incorrect) output, just so there is no misunderstanding what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: I have added the incorrect output, where xmlns is missing from the Area element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in your source XML are all in a namespace. I think your original problem your described was because you were creating new `Message` elements in no namespace, and so they appeared in the output as `<Message xmlns="">`. Your attempt to solve it actually removes namespaces from all elements, which is not really want.

So, really just need to use the identity template to copy elements are retain their namespace....

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But also change the `Message` template to output it in the correct namespace...

```
<xsl:template match="aaa:Message">  
    <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="@number"/>
    <Message xmlns="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc" number="{$messageNumber}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$templateDoc/aaa:Message[@number=$messageNumber]/@symbol"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Message>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:aaa="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc" exclude-result-prefixes="aaa">
<!-- Transform -s:"translation.xml" -xsl:"merge_files.xsl" -o:"updated_translation.xml" +templateFile="source.xml" -versionmsg:off -->

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="templateFile"/>

    <xsl:variable name="templateDoc" select="$templateFile/aaa:Area" />
    <xsl:variable name="source" select="/" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Getting everything except @symbol from the translation. @symbol is fetched from source/template file. -->
    <xsl:template match="aaa:Message">  
        <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="@number"/>
        <Message xmlns="urn:aaa-bbb-ccc" number="{$messageNumber}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$templateDoc/aaa:Message[@number=$messageNumber]/@symbol"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it is finally working! So I was creating new Message elements in no namespace... I see.